# Save OLE Embedded documents in Outlook email to file

Tags: delphi, outlook

I am using late binding to connect to MS Outlook and to open and extract info from outlook emails using the `MailItem`object.

I am trying to save attachments to file. This is fairly straightforward in most instances using the `Attachment` object and its `SaveAsFile` method.

However, it does not work where the `Attachment` `Type` is `olOLE`. I believe this only relates to documents embedded in emails created in RTF format (hopefully few and far between nowadays).

Via the `Attachment` object it is possible to access `MAPI` properties not exposed by the object model using its `PropertyAccessor`.

The relevant `MAPI` property for OLE objects is `PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ`, which can be accessed using the PropertyInspector as in the following example:

```
Function SaveOLEAttachmentToFile(Attachment:Variant; fn:String): boolean;
  var
   OPA, PropName : Variant;
begin
 Result := false;
 OPA := Attachment.PropertyAccessor;
 PropName := 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3701000D '; //PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ
 ?????? := OPA.GetProperty(PropName);
end;
```

I am stuck at this point as I can't know work out what Delphi type to save the data to and I am not even sure this is possible having read the MS documentation ([Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagattachdataobject-canonical-property)). `PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ` returns a `PT_OBJECT`. I am hoping that this object contains the raw data which (if I could work out how to access it in `Delphi`) can be simply saved to a file. However, the documentation suggests it may not be that simple and it's possible I may have to work with `Extended MAPI`. I have spent a few hours researching the latter with no concrete result other than a headache. I appreciate I could use Redemption, but I don't want to use a third party tool for something which is fairly minor in the round.

If anyone can advise as to a data type to hold the `PT_OBJECT` from which it can be simply saved to file that would be my route one.

Failing that, if I need to dig deeper into `MAPI`, I would be grateful if anyone could clarify/amplify my research so far. I have the following steps:

1. Initialize `MAPI`.
2. Get an `IMAPIPROP` interface. I think I should be getting the interface from my `Attachment` object and the following seems to work (ie compiles and executes without problems): `MAPIPROP := IUnknown(Attachment.MAPIObject) as IMAPIPROP`. Failing that, I would have to cast the parent `MailItem` to `IMAPIPROP` interface and work my way down to the attachment via `GetAttachmentTable`.
3. Load the attachment data into an `IStream`: `if Succeeded(MAPIPROP.OpenProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ, IStream, STGM_READ, 0, IUnknown(SourceStream)) then`
4. Extract the data from the `IStream` and save to file

I have failed to get as far as point 3 as something would seem to be wrong with my initial casting to `IMAPIPROP` albeit it does not cause any violations. I have tried reading a single property from the `MailItem` cast to `IMAPIPROP` using the following code:

```
if (Succeeded(HrGetOneProp(MAPIPROP, PR_SUBJECT, Prop))) then
```

And I get an access violation. Likewise if I cast the `Attachment` object and query an attachment property I also get a violation. I don't think the problem lies with the call to `HrGetOneProp`, I think it has to be the casting to IMAPIPROP.

Any pointers re the above would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`PropertyAccessor` (and the Outlook Object Model in general) does not handle `PT_OBJECT` type properties.

What you need to do is open the `PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ` property as `IStorage`, and then extract the data from there (it depends on the actual type of the attachment). You can see the data in the streams in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - select the message, click `IMessage` button on the OutlookSpy rubbon, go to the `GetAttachmentTable` tab, double click on the attachment to open it, select the `PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ` property, right click, select `IMAPIProp::OpenProperty`, then `IStorage`.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am also its author) is an option, its version of [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`SaveAsFile` handles OLE attachment for the most popular formats (Word, Excel, bitmap, Power Point, Adobe PDF, etc.) - create an instance of the [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object (using either `CrealeOleObject` or [RedemptionLoader](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/security.htm#redemptionloader)) and use `RDOSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject` method (pass either `Attachment` or `MailItem` object) to get back [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) or [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm) object respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but keen to avoid third party solutions unless absolutely necessary and have posted an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer to my question, but I have thought of an alternative solution. What I am ultimately trying to do is convert a msg email as a pdf. To do that I need to extract the body and then somehow insert the embedded images. With an html email this seemed pretty straightforward ((1) extract all the attachments to a folder, (2) parse the html body for references to SRC IMG and update the location of the image to reference the saved files and (3) save the edited html body to file and open it in Word and save as PDF).

RTF emails cannot be handled in this way. However, for my specific problem there is a much easier way to achieve what I need for all email types using `Outtlook` and `Word`.

Use the `MailItem.SaveAs` function and save the email in either html format or mthml. The former format will save all embedded images to a sub-folder (in png and jpg formats) should you need them for any other reason. once you have your html file, open it with Word and save to PDF.

If Office is not a solution then you need to figure Istorage or use one of the Extended MAPI solutions such as Redemption.

For Delphi users there are also the following commercial offerings that I have come across in my recent travels:

[IMIBO](https://imibo.com/imidev/delphi/les/index.html)

[Scalabium](http://www.scalabium.com)

[Rapware](https://www.rapware.com/order/order-easy-mapi)

I did come across one more solution which I can't find at the moment! Will post an update if I do.